# Claiming an HID device using webusb

Tags: javascript, hid, webusb

I don't seem to be able to claim hid interface using webusb. I'm trying to write a yubikey OATH wrapper

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters: filters}).then(...);
```

> USBDevice {usbVersionMajor: 2, usbVersionMinor: 0, usbVersionSubminor: 0, deviceClass: 0, deviceSubclass: 0, …}configuration: USBConfiguration {configurationValue: 1, configurationName: null, interfaces: Array(2)}configurations: [USBConfiguration]deviceClass: 0deviceProtocol: 0deviceSubclass: 0deviceVersionMajor: 3deviceVersionMinor: 4deviceVersionSubminor: 9manufacturerName: "Yubico"opened: falseproductId: 273productName: "Yubikey NEO OTP+CCID"serialNumber: "0005610818"usbVersionMajor: 2usbVersionMinor: 0usbVersionSubminor: 0vendorId: 4176__proto__: USBDevice
>      // ykey contains the device now 
>       USBDevice {usbVersionMajor: 2, usbVersionMinor: 0, usbVersionSubminor: 0, deviceClass: 0, deviceSubclass: 0, …}

```
ykey.open(...).then(...);
ykey.claimInterface(0)
```

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
>   Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to claim interface.

I suspect this to be a siimlar issue as with the chrome.usb api. Should I write a udev rule to not use the usbhid driver on that device to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an IRC Conversation, [Reilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275660) mentioned

> The HID driver must not be loaded, so a udev rule is the way to go.
>
> The restriction comes from the OS because when the HID driver is loaded that interface is "claimed" so Chrome can't claim it for itself.