# WebUSB: can't open device

Tags: usb, webusb

I am trying to open a device through WebUSB on Chromium but `device.open` fails with `DOMException: Access denied.`.

Looking at `chrome://device-log`, this errors seems to come from chrome being denied file access by the OS:

```
[17:53:21] USB device added: path=/dev/bus/usb/001/012 vendor=1204 "Cypress Semiconductor", product=62002 "USBUART", serial="610002091C052E84", guid=a653ca6a-9fb4-4d35-bf4b-4b4fb13c927c
[17:53:36] Failed to open /dev/bus/usb/001/012: Operation not permitted (1)
```

That is weird because I configured a udev rule to specifically not have that, and Chromium is ran by me who is part of the plugdev group:

```
nino@dell$ whoami
nino
nino@dell$ groups nino
nino : nino adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker signald
nino@dell$ ps -u nino | grep chrome
<pid> ? 00:00:28 chrome
<some similar lines>
nino@dell$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-cybres.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04b4", MODE="777", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45701609/8186898) says that even with the right permissions, Chrome might not be able to open the device because it is claimed by another process, but I do not know how I could go about checking who claimed the interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what type of device you have which makes it more difficult to understand why it might be failing. Please look at this post to see if it can help you identify the modules in use by the device: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60078/find-out-which-modules-are-associated-with-a-usb-device

Comment: You should run `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/012` to double check that your udev rule is actually working and the device really has 777 permissions.

Comment: @DavidGrayson yes it does, which means that the udev rule is rightfully applied, which is what makes me scratch my head

Comment: What kind of Chromium are you running?  Is it a "snap" on Ubuntu by any chance?  [Why I'm asking](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1780678).

Comment: Btw I bypassed this by using WebMIDI instead of WebUSB and using Chrome instead of Chromium. Not an actual "fix" but might be a solution.